# Was bedeutet "pur" in Werbungssätzen?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Ich sehe sehr oft, dass in Werbungssätzen das Wort "pur" benutzt wird.
Was bedeutet das genau im Kontext?
Warum benutzt man das so oft in der Werbung?

z.B. Genuss-Pur, Werbungpur, lebepur, usw..
Ich habe mehrere Bespiele gesehen, jetzt kann ich mich aber an die nicht mehr erinnern.

Comment: I suggest to refer the result of https://www.google.com/search?q=pur+bedeutung , and then explain, what is not clear in it.

Comment: @peterh,I am interested in a translation in context advertising, and off course I can google...

Comment: Yes, the site wants to become a repository of answers which can't be found easily by googling :-) So, google first, check what you've found, and then ask for what you did not.

Comment: @peterh, There are more stupid questions here, that one just can google.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Pur" ist das gleiche wie englisch "pure". Der "pure Genuss" ist Genuss ohne irgendwelche Verfälschungen oder Einschränkungen, sozusagen das Höchste der Gefühle. Ein Synonym für "pur" ist "rein".

Comment: Ich hätte vielleicht noch sagen sollen, dass "rein" ein Synonym für "pur" ist.

Comment: Du kannst Deine Antworten editieren und nachträglich verbessern.